# How to connect with Multiple Salesforce instances using VBA in Access

Tags: vba, salesforce, odbc, ms-access-2010

How can I make connections to multiple Salesforce instances using VBA in MS Access under Windows 10?

My goal is to compare tables between 2 instances (Production and development) of Salesforce. I'm using VBA in MS Access and the [ODBC Salesforce driver](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/link-to-or-import-data-from-salesforce-7375ffb6-1d6a-46f1-bb0c-c6ac3c58f5a0) to make a linked table to Salesforce. I am successfully connecting to either of the 2 instances using separate Access sessions (close and reopen Access) but cannot get 2 connections (at the same time and/or sequentially) in a single Access session. The issue appears to be that the MS ODBC Salesforce driver is not allowing more than one Salesforce instance to be connected in the same session.

I have tried.

- Changing the connection string followed by the RefreshLink method of TableDefs
- setting TableDef object = nothing
- changing order of execution

Here is stripped down code snippet that can reproduce the issue.

Sub Demo()

```
'Replace these constant values with your ID and passowords
Const PRODUSER = "MyIDOPROD@Salesforce.com"
Const PRODPASS = "MyPasswordPROD"
Const DEVEUSER = "MyIDTEST@test.Salesforce.com"
Const DEVEPASS = "MyPasswordDEVE"

DemoLinkTable "DEV", DEVEUSER, DEVEPASS
DemoLinkTable "PRD", PRODUSER, PRODPASS
```

Function DemoLinkTable(Instance, UserName, Password)

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim LinkTable As TableDef
Set db = Application.CurrentDb
   
Set LinkTable = db.CreateTableDef(Instance)
LinkTable.SourceTableName = "AbbVie.Product_vod__c"
ConnectionString = "ODBC;DRIVER={Salesforce};PWD={" & Password & "}" & ";UID={" & UserName & "}"
If Instance = "DEV" Then ConnectionString = ConnectionString & ";URL=test.salesforce.com;"
LinkTable.Connect = ConnectionString
db.TableDefs.Append LinkTable
Debug.Print "Connection String"
Debug.Print "  As set", ConnectionString
Debug.Print "  Actual", LinkTable.Connect
```

Substituting the appropriate constant values for my ID and Passwords, the output appears something like this.

Connection String
As set      ODBC;DRIVER={Salesforce};PWD={DEVEPASS};UID={DEVEUSER};URL=test.salesforce.com;
Actual      ODBC;DRIVER={Salesforce};PWD={DEVEPASS};UID={DEVEUSER};URL=test.salesforce.com;
Connection String
As set      ODBC;DRIVER={Salesforce};PWD={PRODPASS};UID={PRODUSER}
Actual      ODBC;DRIVER={Salesforce};PWD={DEVEPASS};UID={DEVEUSER};URL=test.salesforce.com;

As you can see, the Connection properly of the 2nd table never changes to the supplied value.

How can I either do 2 different connections at once or remove the old connection and establish a new connection?

Thanks for the assist!

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about having two instances, suggest putting your function inside of a class and then creating two instances of that class.

Main Sub Routine

```
Sub DatabaseQuery_Example()

    Dim myProdConnection As New DBCONNECTION
    myProdConnection.Instance = ""
    myProdConnection.UserName = ""
    myProdConnection.Password = ""
    myProdConnection.DemoLinkTable

    Dim myDevConnection As New DBCONNECTION
    myDevConnection.Instance = ""
    myDevConnection.UserName = ""
    myDevConnection.Password = ""
    myDevConnection.DemoLinkTable
    
End Sub
```

Connection Class (This Example the class is named DBCONNECTION)

```
Option Explicit
' These are properties
    Public Instance As String
    Public UserName As String
    Public Password As String

    
Sub DemoLinkTable()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim LinkTable As TableDef
    Set db = Application.CurrentDb
       
    Set LinkTable = db.CreateTableDef(Instance)
    LinkTable.SourceTableName = "AbbVie.Product_vod__c"
    ConnectionString = "ODBC;DRIVER={Salesforce};PWD={" & Password & "}" & ";UID={" & UserName & "}"
    If Instance = "DEV" Then ConnectionString = ConnectionString & ";URL=test.salesforce.com;"
    LinkTable.Connect = ConnectionString
    db.TableDefs.Append LinkTable
    Debug.Print "Connection String"
    Debug.Print "  As set", ConnectionString
    Debug.Print "  Actual", LinkTable.Connect
End Sub
```

Comment: Despite my trying really hard to ask the question clearly I think we're using different definitions of "Instance." I used that term to mean a separate "organization or org" of the Salesforce software as a service. I have a Production org and a Development org which require separate logins and are reached by different URLs. My issue is that the ODBC driver does not seem to allow for connections to 2 different Salesforce orgs in the same Access session. Try again?

Comment: Also note that I edited the original post and added link to the instructions where I found how to use this driver. Paragraph 2.

Comment: Did you try the example above, if so what was the error message you were getting? Also you mentioned you are okay closing connection 1 and then opening connection 2. You can use ```db.Close``` and then ```Set db = Nothing```